# Load local file using Netlify functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, netlify

I've written a script which takes a JSON file and outputs it to an API endpoint using Netlify's `Functions` feature (https://functions.netlify.com/). For the most part, this works without a hitch, however, one of my endpoints has a lot of text and for ease of editing, I've split the large text blocks into markdown files which I then loaded into the endpoint.

Locally, this works perfectly, but when deployed I get a console error saying `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 ()`. I presume this is because I used a node `fs` method and Netlify doesn't allow that, however, I can't find any information about this.

The code I've used is here:

```js
const marked = require('marked')
const clone = require('lodash').cloneDeep
const fs = require('fs')
const resolve = require('path').resolve
const data = require('../data/json/segments.json')

// Clone the object
const mutatedData = clone(data)

// Mutate the cloned object
mutatedData.map(item => {
  if (item.content) {
    const file = fs.readFileSync(resolve(`./src/data/markdown/${item.content}`), 'utf-8')
    item.content = marked(file)
  }
})

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  callback(null, {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({data: mutatedData})
  });
}
```

I've also attempted to replace

```js
  const file = fs.readFileSync(resolve(`./src/data/markdown/${item.content}`), 'utf-8')
```

with

```js
  const file = require(`../data/markdown/${item.content}`)
```

but that complains about a loader and I'd like to avoid adding webpack configs if possible as I'm using `create-react-app`, besides, I doubt it will help as I'd still be accessing the file-system after build time.

Has anyone else come across this issue before?

Comment: We'll probably need more information about the error that is happening. Can you check your logs (or add logging) for exceptions/warning messages/etc?

Comment: So the only error I get is a console error when deployed to Netlify, which says: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 ()`

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Netlify - is there no way to check the server side logs? A 502 could mean anything.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue is a Netlify one (it's serverless Lambda functions).

Answer (score 2):

At the time when this answer is written (September 2019), Netlify does not seem to upload auxiliary files to AWS Lambda, it appears that only the script where the `handler` is exported will be uploaded. Even if you have multiple scripts exporting multiple handlers, Netlify seems to upload them into isolated "containers" (different AWS instances), which means the scripts will not be able to see each other in relative paths. Disclaimer: I only tested with a free account and there could be settings that I'm not aware of.

Workaround:

For auxiliary scripts, make them into `NPM` packages, add into `package.json` and `require` them in your main script. They will be installed and made available to use.

For static files, you can host them on Netlify just like before you have AWS Lambda, and make `http` requests to fetch the files in your main script.